# Solve the ODE: is my work correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Solve the following IVP.
>
> $$y''(t)+y'(t)+\frac{5}{4}y(t)=g(t) \text{ where }g(t)= \begin{cases} 
>        \sin(t) & 0\leq t<\pi \\
>        0 & t\geq\pi     \end{cases}\text{ and }y(0)=y'(0)=0 $$

**My procedure:**

For $t\geq0:$

$$
    y''(t)+y'(t)+\frac{5}{4}y(t)=\sin(t)+\sin(t-\pi)\theta(x-\pi) \\
    \mathcal{L}\left\{y''(t)+y'(t)+\frac{5}{4}y(t)\right\}= 
    \mathcal{L}\left\{\sin(t)+\sin(t-\pi)\theta(x-\pi)\right\} \\
  \left(s^2+s+\frac54\right)\mathcal{L}\left\{y(t)\right\}=\frac1{s^2+1}+\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+1}\\
\xrightarrow{\text{partial fractions}}
\\ y(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{-\frac{16}{17}\left(\frac{s}{s^2+1}\right)+\frac{4}{17}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+1}\right)+\frac{16}{17}\left(\frac{s+\frac12-\frac12}{\left(s+\frac12\right)^2+1}\right)+
\frac{12}{17}\left(\frac{s}{\left(s+\frac12\right)^2+1}\right)+e^{-\pi s}\left(-\frac{16}{17}\left(\frac{s}{s^2+1}\right)+\frac{4}{17}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+1}\right)+\frac{16}{17}\left(\frac{s+\frac12-\frac12}{\left(s+\frac12\right)^2+1}\right)+\frac{12}{17}\left(\frac{s}{\left(s+\frac12\right)^2+1}\right)\right)
\right\}
$$
After taking the inverse Laplace Transform of the above expression, we obtain the following (I will not write the calculations since they will occupy too much space):
$$\boxed{y(t)=\frac{4}{17}\left(e^{-t/2}-e^{(\pi-t)/2}\theta(t-\pi)-\theta(t-\pi)+1\right)\sin(t)++\frac{16}{17}\left(e^{-t/2}-e^{(\pi-t)/2}\theta(t-\pi)+\theta(t-\pi)-1\right)\cos(t)}$$
Would this be correct? I cannot check my work so it is difficult for me to find out if I am right.

Comment: Is $\theta$ the Heaviside step ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to write

$$ y(t) = \frac{4}{17}\left(e^{-t/2}-e^{-(t-\pi)/2}\theta(t-\pi)-\theta(t-\pi)+1\right)\sin t + \\ 
\frac{16}{17}\left(e^{-t/2}-e^{-(t-\pi)/2}\theta(t-\pi)+\theta(t-\pi)-1\right)\cos t $$

this can be rewritten as

$$ y(t) = \begin{cases} 
\displaystyle \frac{4}{17}(e^{-t/2}+1)\sin t + \frac{16}{17}(e^{-t/2}-1)\cos t , && 0 < t < \pi \\
\displaystyle -(e^{\pi/2}-1)e^{-t/2}\left( \frac{4}{17}\sin t + \frac{16}{17}\cos t \right), && t > \pi
\end{cases} $$

By inspection you have a particular solution 
$$ y_p(t) = -\frac{16}{17}\cos t + \frac{4}{17}\sin t $$

that satsifies
$$ y'' + y + \frac{5}{4}y = \sin t $$

and the homogeneous solution of the form
$$ y_h(t) = e^{-t/2}(a\cos t + b\sin t) $$

for $$ y'' + y + \frac{5}{4}y = 0 $$

Also, the first derivative is
$$ y'(t) = \begin{cases} 
\displaystyle \left(-\frac{4}{17}e^{-t/2} + \frac{4}{17} \right)\cos t - 
\left(\frac{18}{17}e^{-t/2}-\frac{16}{17} \right)\sin t, && 0 < t < \pi \\
\displaystyle (e^{\pi/2}-1)e^{-t/2}\left(\frac{4}{17}\cos t + \frac{18}{17}\sin t \right), && t > \pi
\end{cases} $$

The initial condition $y(0) = y'(0) = 0$ and continuity for $y(\pi)$, $y'(\pi)$ are all satisfied

Comment: Yes, everything should be in terms of $t$. I’ll fix it now. Thanks for pointing that out. Thanks for adding the inspection part

Comment: You also has $e^{-(\pi-t)/2}$ instead of $e^{-(t-\pi)/2}$

Comment: yup I realized, in my paper I had it correct, distraction mistake. Thanks.